# Options for building docker images for pi 3 on amd64?

Tags: pi-3, emulation, qemu

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian with Docker in a headless setup just fine. I've been building an application with docker-compose directly on the Pi, and while that's working just fine, it's enormously slow. I have an amd64 machine with an 8 core processor and 12gb RAM (running Mint) that I'd prefer to be taking advantage of, but I'm not having much luck with setting QEMU up.

I've worked through several of the answers here regarding emulating a Raspberry Pi with QEMU but I've had no luck. Scripts silently failing, syntax errors with commands, dead links, etc.

My question is- are there any other options for building docker containers for the Pi on different architectures besides QEMU? If that's all there is, I'll try to keep digging. I've never worked with QEMU before and I'm running into opaque walls where I'm typing in commands from blog articles with no explanation or understanding and I'd prefer to avoid that. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!